# Install applications from play store in android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play

I installed Play Store in my android emualtor. for some reasons I can't download many applications to my Emulator, because when it says "your device isn't compatible with this version" or just not appearing when I'm searching it.

Is there any way to "disguise" my emulator as Nexus 5 so that many application won't block me from downloading it?

Comment: I didn't think emulators had a connection to the internet. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Which Android emulator are you using? Genymotion or standard emulator?

Comment: Have you tried to download the same app in a real device? You might get a same message.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the perfect Android emulator called: Genymotion: http://www.genymotion.com/, and then take look at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zvTYDcYOFyw to set up the Google play service on it. It works perfectly, and I can have different devices to emulate and download what I want.